# Detect blank row in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a c# datagridview control where I want to detect that whether my previous row was blank so that I can pop up a message informing user that a blank row can be added to database . I am new to c# .

Comment: Can you add the code that you are working with?

Comment: What does "my previous row" mean in this context?  If you know a row number, you can get the cells in the row.  Then, you can look at the cell content.  By the way, you probably want to tag this with `win forms` and remove the `ado.net` tag (since what you are asking has nothing to do with database access)

Comment: You'll have to provide a better description that clarifies operations and context and be more specific on what part of your code causes a problems, also posting that code.

Comment: your question is unclear. please provide code and image. do you mean blank or null? one blank cell or an entire row?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
        {            
            bool emptyRow = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count;i++ )
            {

 // depending on which .NET version you are targeting...       
 // you can use IsNullOrEmpty()          
 // if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value).ToString().IsNullOrEmpty())
 // this row is empty
                if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value != null)
                {
                    emptyRow = false;
                    return;    
                }    
                else MessageBox.Show("this is an empty row, do something!");    
            }    
        }
```

---

**Update:**
Sure you can use whatever event and clear out the row. Your question is not clear to me.

```
private void dataGridView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
  {
    // 1 get your current row and         
    DataGridViewRow dgr = dataGridView.CurrentRow;

    // 2 check if empty like above, then delete as needed with previous code
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use the code on row enter event ??

Comment: Also i only want to check previous row only . Is there any code by which i can get if the previous tow is completely empty ?

Comment: What does "previous row" mean?  The row above wherever the select is? The last row that they user selected? Something else?

Comment: The row above wherever the select is